# AgnularJS ng-model directive usage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why in the following `AngularJS` [example](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_expression_3) `ng-model` directive is used? It works without this directive - as one can test it by removing the `ng-model` directive and setting `myCol` variable to any valid background color value. What is the use of `ng-model` directive here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<p>Change the value of the input field:</p>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="myCol='lightblue'">

<input style="background-color:{{myCol}}" ng-model="myCol">

</div>

<p>AngularJS resolves the expression and returns the result.</p>

<p>The background color of the input box will be whatever you write in the input field.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-model provides two-way binding, so although ng-init sets the initial value, if you want to be able to dynamically respond to user input (changing the colour via the input) then you need ng-model.

Comment: I now see now the use of what you stated above about `two-way` binding. In [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_binding), if I  remove `ng-model="quantity"` from `Quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="quantity">` and click on `Run` button on top, then changing the Quantity value in the right input box does not change the `Total in dollar: ` value. Thank you for explaining the logic behind the use of `ng-model`